# CSS compatibility in samsung galaxy 2

Tags: android, css, html

Does anyone know if the Samsung Galaxy 2 browser supports the following css tags:

```
input:required:focus:invalid
input:required:invalid
input:required
input:required:focus:valid
```

Comment: I am building a hybrid android application for the android environment. for samsung galaxy 2 in particular.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can see a list of WebKit versions based on Android version [here](http://jimbergman.net/webkit-version-in-android-version/), note the Galaxy 2 shipped with 2.3, but now supports 4.0.3.

Webkit does support the selectors you require.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at this website too:
http://alistapart.com/article/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet
Your can use all kinds of stylesheets for your android app.